# Automate copying new file in specific folder to clipboard

Tags: automator, copy-paste, gift

I'm using a macOS app to create GIFs (called [GifFox](https://gifox.app/)) but the app does not offer a feature to auto-save to clipboard. However, I can define the location the GIF will be saved to. How can I create an automation that:

1. listens for new files in this folder and auto-copies them to the clipboard (preferred UX)
2. that copies the newest file in a folder to the clipboard after I execute a certain shortcut (less optimal).

Comment: Folder action with a shellscript running `pbcopy` should work.

Comment: @nohillside pbcopy/paste only works with text, (including PostScript and RTF.) Also, I'm not sure that Clipboard stores GIF - it would  be converted to TIFF.

Comment: @benwiggy Ah, right, images are a different beast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save this following **AppleScript** code in **Script Editor.app** as "File_To_Clipboard.scpt" (or whatever name you want) to your /Users/**your_short_name**/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/ folder.

```
property theFile : missing value

on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    
    set theFile to POSIX path of theNewItems
    set the clipboard to POSIX file theFile
    
end adding folder items to
```

Then in **Finder**, right click the Folder that your GIF files will be saved to and select **Folder Actions Setup...** then select your new "File_To_Clipboard.scpt" file to attach to that Folder.

Now anytime a file is added to that Folder, that file will be copied to your clipboard

Comment: However, if more than one file is added, this is going to choke.  You even gave the variable a name that indicates more than one new item...

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Note that I had to create this `Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`-folder first to put the `File_To_Clipboard.scpt`-script there. Reading your answer it sounded like this already exists.

Comment: Unfortunately, this just stopped working for me. (14.0 (23A344))

Comment: OK, nvm, disabling and *re-enabling* the folder actions in the "Service" dropdown settings popup fixed this.